# Inferring mother's allele probability based on father and children

Tags: genetics, homework, allele

I am currently in the process of analyzing our family's genome. I do have access to his, mine and our father's genome, but not to our mother's (deceased). I was wondering how I could combine our 3 genomes to infer information about our mother's.

With regard to two different genes I am faced with these two situations:

**Gene 1:**

- Father: GG
- Brother: GG
- Me: GA
- Mother: *Likely AA, less likely GA but most likely not GG or otherwise I would also have GG?*

**Gene 2:**

- Father: GG
- Brother: GG
- Me: AA
- Mother: *No idea, if she had GA I would have at most GA, if she had AA my brother shouldn't have GG. Does this mean a mutation is involved?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gene 1: Mother was almost surely GA (she couldn't had been AA because then both children were GA). Gene 2: Mutation or some other non-Mendelian inheritance or ... well ... different father.

Comment: In a basic biology class one of the first steps in understanding Mendelian inheritance is always building [Punnett squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square). I recommend you play around with those, with all your different guesses about mothers, to figure out what makes sense and doesn't. You'll learn more that way than asking someone else to give you the answer.

Comment: need to consider haplotype  (https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/haplotype-haplotypes-142/)